# String method returning null

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I query the firebase and get the expected answer, however, when I return the String, it is null ... inside the method it is not null!

```
class Util {
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String name;
  List<User> users = [];

  String getNomeById(bool retirada, String userId) {
    firestore
        .collection('users')
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: userId)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      users = snapshot.documents.map((d) => User.fromDocument(d)).toList();

      if (retirada) {
        name = users[0].name;
        //  print(name); name is here!
      } else {
        name = 'Other';
      }
    });

    return name; // IS NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you getting a `Stream` from firestore? Is there any special reason for this or are you just trying to get what's returned by that query?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore 
I'm just trying to get what's returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just get the returned query, use the `getDocuments` method instead of `snapshots()`. It returns a `Future<QuerySnapshot>`. With this you can use your existing code to correctly return a `String`. Ex:

```dart
Future<String> getNomeById(bool retirada, String userId) async {
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await firestore
    .collection('users')
    .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: userId)
    .getDocuments();
  
  users = snapshot.documents.map((d) => User.fromDocument(d)).toList();

  if (retirada) {
    name = users[0].name;
  } else {
    name = 'Other';
  }
  return name;
}
```

Comment: thanks but now...
 I'm trying to use the return in a widget
 return AlertDialog(
      title: Text(u.getNomeById(retirada, userId) ?? 'teste'),

 type 'Future<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: @Manzini That should be asked as a separate question, or you can look at other questions, but you need to `await`. You should read into `Future`s.